# This university is "a perfect match" for me?

Tags: grammar

I wanted to explain why I chose to apply to a university and I wanted to say that this university matches? me. ( like the stuff they offer and what they value)
Are there any other way to say this formally ?

Comment: Your question will be improved, and you may get a better answer, if you use the [edit] link to add a sentence _you_ wrote to express this thought in English.

Comment: Maybe "That university [*suits*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/suit) me." See definitions 13, 14.

Comment: "Choice " perhaps